# How can I make xargs execute two commands?

Tags: shell, command-line, syntax, amazon-s3, xargs

I tried this

> s3cmd ls s3://somebucket/data/ | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -I
>   %s s3cmd -v -c s3.cfg cp %s 's3://anotherbucket/data/' && s3cmd
>   -c s3.cfg rm %s -v

it does not work, of course, because the second command (`s3cmd rm`) is not treated as part of the xargs argument...

How can I do it?

Background is that the move operation of the `s3cmd` in my case appears not to delete the source file, so I wanted to replace it with a copy and a delete, which appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up just envoking sh (took that hint form the xarg manpage) and working from there on, like this:

> s3cmd ls s3://somebucket/data/ | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -n 1 sh -c '
>   s3cmd -v -c s3.cfg cp $0 's3://anotherbucket/data/'; s3cmd -c s3.cfg
>   rm $0 -v';

Comment: you could also use `parallel` instead of `xargs`. Q: why do you not accept your own answer?

Comment: Mate, your caps key appears to be broken.